# Dynamic fill ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I don't know how much column exactly I need - I manage to generate it using Converters.

Code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var config = value as ColumnConfig;
        if (config != null)
        {
            var grdiView = new GridView();
            foreach (var column in config.Columns)
            {
                var binding = new Binding(column.DataField);
                grdiView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = column.Header, DisplayMemberBinding = binding });
            }
            return grdiView;
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
```

But now there is a problem with filling the listview with data. How can I do it? I've tried fill it with

```
List<List<string>>
```

but it doesn't work.

All I need to do is to fill ListView with strings.

Any idea?

Comment: i can't be sure of what you did but try ObservableCollection insted of List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var config = value as ColumnConfig;
        if (config != null)
        {
            var grdiView = new GridView();
            for (int i = 0; i < config.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                var column = config.Columns[i];
                var binding = new Binding("["+i +"]");
                grdiView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = column.Header, DisplayMemberBinding = binding});
            }
            return grdiView;
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
```

and you can bind to

```
List<List<string>>
```